# Word count query in Django

Tags: django, count, character, words

Given a model with both Boolean and TextField fields, I want to do a query that finds records that match some criteria AND have more than "n" words in the TextField. Is this possible? e..g.:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    ...    
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True,)
    has_media = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

This is easy:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(completed=True,has_media=True)
```

but how can I filter for a subset of those records where the "notes" field has more than, say, 25 words?

Comment: I am sure you can run a lambda and filter it out after the data is recieved from the DB, but there's a better way. I can't remember what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Item.objects.extra(where=["LENGTH(notes) - LENGTH(REPLACE(notes, ' ', ''))+1 > %s"], params=[25])
```

This code uses Django's [`extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) queryset method to add a custom `WHERE` clause. The calculation in the `WHERE` clause basically counts the occurances of the "space" character, assuming that all words are prefixed by exactly one space character. Adding one to the result accounts for the first word.

Of course, this calculation is only an approximation to the real word count, so if it has to be precise, I'd do the word count in Python.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what SQL need to be run in order for the DB to do the work, which is really what we want, but you can monkey-patch it.

Make an extra fields named wordcount or something, then extend the save method and make it count all the words in notes before saving the model.

The it is trivial to loop over and there is still no chance that this denormalization of data will break since the save method is always run on save.

But there might be a better way, but if all else fails, this is what I would do.

Comment: Agree with the solution, but this isn't monkey-patching.

Comment: You are right, its not. Just couldn't find a better word for it. It just feels a little "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

I am here, after 12.5 years to give my glorious answer! Jokes aside, I think people might still search for this and want a more modern solution.

You can define a custom function and use that with annotate like that:

```py
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Func

class WordCount(Func):
    function = 'CHAR_LENGTH'
    name = 'word_count'
    template = "(%(function)s(%(expressions)s) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(%(expressions)s, ' ', '')))"
    output_field = IntegerField()
```

```
Posts.objects.filter(likes__gte=200).annotate(text_word_count=WordCount("abstract"))
```